# Accessibility : Set focus upon closing Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, focus, accessibility, fancybox-2

I'm trying to make Fancybox 2 accessible, but I can not set focus on the opening link when Fancybox is closed.

I tried this function but it does not work:

```
beforeClose: function() {
    $(".fancybox").eq(this.index).focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just said to yourself "*... when Fancybox is closed* " so use the `afterClose` callback instead  like :

```
afterClose: function() {
    $(this.element).focus();
}
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tTxmP/)** (easier to perceive in Chrome)

`$(this.element)` refers to `$(this)` in fancybox ... the link from where you invoked fancybox.